# Weird Scenario where I am Missing an element when using ResultSet java inside lambda

Tags: java, jdbc

My ResultSet misses an element when I iterate over the result inside of a lambda function , and assign the results to a variable outside the lambda function. But the same works fine when I declare a variable inside the lambda function, add values to it and return it as part of the function.

I tried placing a count variable and checking both scenarios to see how many times the while loop is run and I confirmed it runs one lesser.

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
getTemplate.query("Some Query that returns 38251 elements", (ResultSet rs) -> {
     int count = 0;
     while(rs.next()) {
         count++;
         map.put(rs.getString("val"),rs.getString("val2"));
    }
   //count here is 38250
});
map.size() -> 38250 //Missing 1 element
```

But when I do this

```
Map<String,String> correct = getTemplate.query("Some Query that returns 38251 elements", (ResultSet rs) -> {    
     Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
     int count = 0;
     while(rs.next()) {
         count++;
         map.put(rs.getString("val"),rs.getString("val2"));
    }
   //count here is 38251
   return map;
});
correct.size() // 38251 elements
```

Comment: I am using Java 8!

Comment: This makes no sense. An element must have been added to or deleted from the database between the two runs.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Both of these codes have the same logic.